# How to deal with "Document contains at least one immense term" in SOLR?

Tags: solr, lucene

In LUCENE-5472, Lucene was changed to throw an error if a term is too long, rather than just logging a message. This error states that SOLR doesn't accept token larger than  32766

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field="text" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[10, 10, 70, 111, 117, 110, 100, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 111, 110, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 119, 101, 98, 32, 104, 111, 112, 101, 32, 116]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 43225
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:671)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:300)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:234)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:450)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1475)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:239)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:163)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash$MaxBytesLengthExceededException: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 43225
    at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:284)
```

Trying to fix this issue, I added two filters in the schema (in **bold**):

```
<field name="text" type="text_en_splitting" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" termVectors="true" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
**<filter class="solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory" prefixLength="32700"/>
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="32700" />**
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Since the error is still the same (this make me think that the filters are not correctly set up, maybe? )
**Restarting the server is the key** thanks to Mr. Bashetti

The question is which one is better: `LengthFilterFactory` or `TruncateTokenFilterFactory` ? And is it right assuming that a byte is a character (since the filter should remove 'unusual' characters ? )
Thank you!

Comment: why do you have LengthFilterFactory as its going to filters out those tokens *not* having length min through max inclusive.

Comment: because I want to ignore or truncate (or whatever) elements greater than the maximum allowed by SOLR

Comment: Did you restart the solr server after the change ?

Comment: .............I feel like a stupid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that `"SOLR doesn't accept token larger than 32766"`

The issue was because of you have used the String fieldType earlier for you field text and its the same issue you are getting currently after changing the field type because you have not restarted the solr server after the changes.

I don't think there is any need of adding `TruncateTokenFilterFactory` or `LengthFilterFactory`.

But that is left with you and your whats requirement you have.

Comment: well.. I had the same issues before adding the filters, I added those to try to fix it..
plus, according to the [doc](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LengthFilterFactory), it states that 
 "Filters out those tokens *not* having length min through max inclusive"

this means that it should throw away values greater than 32700. Right?

Comment: did you used string fieldType for your text fields before the change?

Comment: that was the key. But now I have a question, Which one is better?  `TruncateTokenFilterFactory` or `LengthFilterFactory`

Comment: no wait, it wasn't String type. The type that had issues was text_en_splitting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111226/discussion-between-salvob-and-abhijit-bashetti).

Comment: I said earlier it was of string type ...for which you got the issue...then you changed the same to text_en_splitting... But didn't restart the solr server after the changes...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors while loading enron_email data from (http://jsonstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/enron.zip) into solr-6.0.0 using the bin/post tool

See excerpts below

> ... contains at least one immense term in field=\"text\" (whose UTF8
>   encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were
>   skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The
>   prefix of the first immense term is: '[78, 97, 110, 99, 121, 32, 83,
>   104, 101, 101, 100, 32, 60, 110, 97, 110, 99, 121, 95, 115, 104, 101,
>   101, 100, 64, 66, 85, 83, 73, 78]...', original message: bytes can be
>   at most 32766 in length; got 43172. Perhaps the document has an
>   indexed string field (solr.StrField) which is too large","code":400}}
>   SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response:
>   java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/enron_emails/update/json/docs ...

**RCA**
The schema field name "text" uses the fieldtype strings is limited to 32766. 
In order to accept data/clobs with length greater than 32766, the field type had to be changed to text_general

**Solution**

A)In Standalone Mode

Editing file $SOLR_HOME/server/solr/core_name/conf/managed-schema ,
I changed

`<field name="text" type="strings"/>` to `<field name="text" type="text_general"/>`

B) In Solrcloud mode (as managed-schema file will be in embedded or own zookeeper)

```
# check collections field "text" definition 
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/enron_emails/schema/fields/text?wt=json&indent=true"

# Modify collections field "text" definition 
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "replace-field":{
     "name":"text",
     "type":"text_general",
     "stored":false } }' "http://localhost:8983/solr/enron_emails/schema?wt=json&indent=true"

# Verify  collections field "text" new definition 
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/enron_emails/schema/fields/text?wt=json&indent=true"
```